# Simple javascript image randomizer doesn't actually load images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently working on a site, where I want the background on the index (in this case an image.) to change every time you enter the site. So this is the solution that I came up with:

```
    var Index = {
    Actions: {
        setBackground: function() {
            var images = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg', '5.jpg'];
            var random = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];

            alert(random);
            $("body").css({'background-image': 'url("../img/backgrounds/' + random + '");'});
        }
    }
}
Index.Actions.setBackground();
```

but for some reason, the background stays white. I did also try the actual switching like this:

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "../img/backgrounds/" + random;
```

But that also did nothing.
Please note that the console is empty.

Here is the CSS for the body object:

```
body {
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    position:relative;
}
```

Is there a reason that this wont work? And if so, how to fix it...

Thanks.

Comment: If you look at network requests, are any of those images loading or failing to load (404?)

Comment: Just verify the image path and names are correct.

Comment: Remove the semicolon from the end of the url() string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this; `$("body").css('background-image', 'url("../img/backgrounds/' + random + '")');`
[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/turbopipp/pwkz557t/)

Correct syntax; [.css( propertyName, value )](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2)